# How to force React to use setState with only function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

consider the following:
`[xState, setXState] = useState<boolean>(false)`

Setting the state could be used either with:
`setXState(false)` or `setXState(() => false))`

I want to force the second way so developer would only be able to use functional set state.

I tried ESLINT but seems as there is no such way, so I thought of overriding REACT library types:

I found the type itself in react `index.d.ts` file:

type SetStateAction = S | ((prevState: S) => S);

So I tried overriding it

`@types/react/index.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace React {
    type SetStateAction<S> = (prevState: S) => S;
}
```

But It didn't help.

Any advice?

** IF it is not clear, I insist on forcing that specific hook. I don't want to create a new hook or use `useReducer` **

Comment: I think useReducer would help

Comment: @JoshLin how it will help

Answer (score 0):

replace all your useState to useReducer, as you said you want to pass function into `setState` that's what reducer means

---

also custom hook can make it in typescript

```js
import {useState} from 'react'

function useStateFn<T>(val:T){
  let [v,setV]=useState(val)
  return [v,setV as (fn:(v:T)=>T)=>void]
}

const Comp = ()=>{
  let [x,setX]=useStateFn(1)
  ....
}
```

Comment: I insist on forbid `setState` without a function. So replacing it with useReducer or new hook does not help

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a custom hook:

```
import {useState} from "react";

const useFunctionalState = (initialState) => {
   const [state, dispatch] = useState(initialState);
   const customDispatch = (fn) => {
      if(typeof fn !== "function") {
         throw new Error("Cannot update the state. Use a function instead");
      }
      dispatch(fn);
   }
   return [state, customDispatch]
}
```